# how to get all currenly logged-in user ids of anonymous user in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7

I have planed to create my own simple chat system. I am using wampserver on windowsxp. I need to get all currently logged-in user ids of anonymouse role in drupal 7. Having those ids we can get user names of all currently logged-in users from user table. so how do i get currently logged in user ids?
plase help me some to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

**"logged-in user ids of anonymous role"** by default Drupal assigns 0 as uid for anonymous role.

If you want to display the users who is online currently, Drupal 7 comes with default block, "Who's online" block.

Goto Structure->Blocks and enable it to your preferred region.

and you can try [Drupal chat](https://drupal.org/project/drupalchat) module for chat feature.